# How to make level intro (2D)

Tags: unity, c#

How do I make it so that when the level starts, the player runs in from off the screen (without input) ready for the player to start moving him and complete the level.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could set the walk animation of the player and then automatically move them in the update.  This might take a smarter script I am guessing you have a player controller that takes input.  I would have a boolean that asks if it is in intro mode or not, if it is, then instead of waiting for input, just force it (not sure how you update your player) but you can use code similar to what you use for moving the player and just force it 'on' while doing animation for a specific amount of time or until the player hits a trigger.